# CLOSE - How to merge mesh in THREE.js (r128)

Tags: javascript, merge, three.js, 3d, mesh

what I want to do is the following, I create a custom shape voxel and I want to merge the different custom voxels into a single one.
I try with:

```
let geom = new THREE.BufferGeometry();

for(let i = 0; i < scene.children.length; i++){
        if(scene.children[i].name === "custom-voxel"){
                geom.merge(scene.children[i].geometry);
        }
}
```

But it doesn't work so I try with:

```
var geometries = [];
for(let i = 0; i < scene.children.length; i++){
        if(scene.children[i].name === "custom-voxel"){
                geometry.push(scene.children[i].geometry.clone());
        }
}

geom = mergeBufferGeometries(geometries);
geom.computeBoundingBox();
var meshh = new THREE.Mesh(
        geom,
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0000ff })
);
```

But in this way it also doesn't work or better it create the all object in the same position, do you have an idea on how I can keep the distance between objects?

Thanks.

Comment: You're calling `geometry.push()` but you're trying to merge the `geometries` array. It looks like you're getting your variable names confused.

Comment: Yeah because I create an array of geometries and I marge later when I do `geom = mergeBufferGeometries(geometries);` that is from BufferGeometryUtils

But with this I lose the position and all the geometries will be put on the same place